# List of dec numbers to 2digit hex in python

Tags: python, list, hex

I have a list of numbers between 0 and 255 in python **3**, which looks like that:

```
numbers = [79, 104, 44, 32, 105, 116, 32, 119, 111, 114, 107, 115, 32, 102, 2, 2]
```

I would like to convert it to a string with hex-numbers like:

```
4f682c20697420776f726b7320660202
```

I do not want the "0x" to be included and very important: Numbers smaller than a should have a trailing zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "".join(hex(num)[2:].zfill(2) for num in numbers)
 # '4f682c20697420776f726b7320660202'
```

Use `hex` to get the hexadecimal representation,

use `[2:]` to get rid of the `0x` part,

use `str.zfill` to ensure zeros as prefix for short ones e.g. `2`,

and lastly join the generator expression by `""` to get a string.